# Sink Mobility in Wireless Sensor Network

Tags: matlab, performance, networking, communication, wireless

```
points = [200, 200;
          200, 180;
          180, 180;
          180, 200;
          40, 40;
          40, 160;
          160, 160;
          160, 40]
for s = 1 : size(points, 1)
  fprintf('Plotting (%d, %d)\n', points(s,1), points(s, 2));
  pause(5);
```

I have done my code this way ... I want to make the location of sink/Base Station mobile so that it moves with a certain velocity... Am i doing right? Because i think it will just consider the last value and will not update live values??
Any suggestions???
    end

Comment: Sink has to move with certain velocity. No matter it moves inside or out of the (100*100m) grid.

Answer (score 0):

you can determine velocity in x and y-axis (`vx` and `vy`) and then generate the position of mobile (`x` and `y`) by `x = v*t + x0` and `y = v*t + y0` equation, where t is time, and `x0` and `y0` are initial positions.

```
x0 = 0; % Start Point
y0 = 0; % Start Point
t=1:0.1:100
vx = 1; % initial velocity 
vy = 1; % initial velocity 
x = vx.*t + x0;
y = vy.*t + y0;
```